# Morpho Butterfly blue wings physics

Tags: visible-light, interference

The morpho buttery have special wings where the colour does not result from pigmentation. Additionally, when the wing is viewed from different angles, the colours change. Why does this happen?

(I know this phenomena occurs because of thin film interference but I don't understand why and how the angle also impacts the colours that we see)

Comment: Years ago, while going through a musty tomb deep in the bowels of the campus library searching for the original Geiger-Marsden paper on alpha scattering, a multi-fold color insert dropped out of the book. It was part of an article by Thompson on hummingbird wing colors, talking about the thin film effects. Anyway, the color you see in thin film interference does change with viewing angle because the thickness of the film changes with viewing angle.

Comment: have you read the wiki entry ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpho#Coloration

Comment: @JonCuster wouldn't the thickness of the film remain constant regardless of the viewing angle?

Comment: @annav yes I did read it but I'm having a bit difficulty understanding why the angle that the light is being viewed from results in a change of colour. Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: @BerryCherolds - the thickness of the film that you are looking through changes with angle (consider the limit as you are looking _along_ the plane of the thin film, not _perpendicular_ to it. Snell's law in full detail covers this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the butterfly wings are a diffraction pattern. If you look at the image in the Wikipedia link posted by Anna, you see that the wings have periodic structures that functionally makes them a diffraction pattern. This diffraction pattern will give you maxima for different wavelengths depending on the angle of the incident and outgoing light. A bit like looking at a CD from different angles.

Comment: sorry do the butterfly wings act as a diffraction pattern because the spacings between the microscopic structures act as slits? Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: They can be slits but they can also be reflective. See this link with the images and compare with the images from the butterfly wings. https://www.newport.com/n/diffraction-grating-physics

Comment: do not use the word diffraction when you should use the word interference!!  the color is not caused by diffraction .... it is caused by interference.

Comment: @BerryCherolds  see my comment above

Comment: Well, I do believe we talk about a diffraction pattern, not an "interference pattern". The wave front coming into the butterfly wings has a long enough coherence length to consider it coherent and then the slits in the diffraction pattern give rise to different waves from the same "source"that interfere destructively or constructively.

Comment: diffraction is a much broader term, it includes important concepts where material waves like water and air bend/spread around a boundary ..... not all diffraction causes interference.  For the DSE specifically quite a few scientist in optics shortened "diffraction pattern" to  "diffraction" but it is misleading outside these circles.  For thin films we actually have NO diffraction, i.e. no spreading or bending is happening .... in thin films we just have pure wave function dynamics ..... if the layers are close to the wavelength thickness the light is transmitted ....

Answer (score 0):

interference is the classical term.  but more basically light of a wavelength that is not the same as the spacing thickness will be reflected.  when the light comes at an angle it sees more thickness so it could be transmitted.